# MediaMetadataRetriever mostly stopped working since update to Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, multimedia

Since I upgraded my Galaxy S2 to Android 4 I am having some weird problem with my audio player application.
Since the upgrade MediaMetadataRetriever doesn't output much info other than the track number and the embedded picture. No title, no artist, pretty much nothing.

I am currently at a loss, as the problem is just made worse that the Android 4.0.3 emulator doesn't have the same problem.

Googling for this didn't help much, although I find it hard to imagine that I would be the only one with this kind of problem. My wife's SGS2 shows the same problem, so I don't expect it to be some strange problem limited to my phone.
Does anybody know if that might be a problem limited to ICS for the SGS2?
Did anybody else experience problems with MediaMetadataRetriever on ICS?
And, I guess most importantly, does anybody have a solution for this?

In case you want to check if my application has that problem on your phone you can get either code or APKs at http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/andrstoryteller

Any general advice on how I might be able to track down the problem would help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will test your sample application when I have a moment but in the meantime you may also want to think about another solution besides MediaMetadataRetriever since it limits your API compatibility and (apparently) doesn't always work. My project, [ServeStream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/), uses a stripped down version of Apache Tika to retrieve the metadata. You may want to consider this approach in your own project. Here is a URL to the Tika jar and the class to do the parsing:

http://servestream.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/servestream/trunk/lib/tika-app-1.0.jar?view=log
http://servestream.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/servestream/trunk/src/net/sourceforge/servestream/utils/MetadataRetriever.java?revision=1033&view=markup

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really worried about requiring API level 10 (Android 2.3.3) as the minimum version in order to be able to use MediaMetadataRetriever, since that anyway is the predominant version in the wild.
I am, however, annoyed by this problem, so I am going to have to have a look around for alternative solutions.
My problem is just that, as far as possible, I'd like to avoid external libraries and just work with what Android offers.

Comment: Actually, per the chart at http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html about 30 percent of devices are running Android 2.2 or below. So you are automatically throwing out 1/3 of your potential user base by limiting the application to 2.3+. MediaMetadataRetriever is simply a wrapper class that calls native C code so it's behavior could certainly vary depending on your version and build.

Comment: I see you switched metadata parser from apache tika to ffmpeg. What are the benefits compared to using android MediaStore?

Comment: There are several benefits. Tika is an extremely large library and only supports a handful of formats. MediaStore only works for files that are stored locally on the device. FFmpeg can parse metadata from nearly any media format and allows me to retrieve it without having to download the file. Are you thinking about using FFmpeg in your own project?

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever is not limited to android-10, it actually works fine on older API levels -- at least back to 2.1.

Comment: That's incorrect. The documentation states it's was added in API 10. It's not included in the compatibility library so it won't work in versions before Android 2.3.3: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same issue on ICS (On Galaxy SII and Galaxy Tab II both running ICS 4.0.3).
This seems to impact only mp3.

I guess one of the solutions as William suggested would be to use an external library but I also prefer to use what android offers rather then external libraries.

What bothers me is that I cannot find other posts reporting the same issue apart from this one. Though, I don't think I am doing it wrong:

I have tried two solutions:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmdr.setDataSource(path);
String title = mmdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

and

```
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream inputStream;
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
mmdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmdr.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
inputStream.close();
String title = mmdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE) always retuns null.

The path is correct and the mp3 file does have the ID3 tag with the title and everything.

A solution that I thought of apart from using an external library would be to query the MediaStore on the file's path:

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE},
                            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?",
                            new String[] { path }, null);

String title;
if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst())
 title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE))
}
```

If the MediaScanner scanned it (it should have), the info should be there. This should also work for API levels before 10.

Basically, what I do in my project is the following: If SDK version is < 10 or the file's extension is mp3 and SDK version is 15, I query the MediaStore, otherwise I use MediaMetaDataRetriever.

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever doesn't work in my ICS too. But your solution with cursor does not work for me either... I get also `null`.

Answer (score 1):

A little update on the situation.
I have just put a couple of Ogg/Vorbis files onto my phone and there it can read the tags properly.
Will have to test with some more files, but maybe this has only stopped working for MP3 files.
Would be cool if I could get a couple of more people with ICS phones to test this.
Anyway, I'm currently looking into an alternative way to get this information, so I probably won't be using MediaMetadataRetriever for much longer.